# NUmber formatting to display green and red in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a custom number formatting where I need to change the numbers from black for postive and red for negative

I have the format as: `[$₹][>9999999]##\,##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹][>99999]##\,##\,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00;`

The formatting is used to displaying lakh and crore number systems. I only need to display the colors.

Comment: Is this not just a case of using a simple Conditional Formatting rule, for that column of numbers?  Set the default font colour to black, and then have a rule for that range that says: =A1<0 (assuming A1 is the first cell in your column) then set the font to red.  I must be missing something...  And sorry, but you mention green in your title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

`[$₹][green]##,##0.00;[$₹][red]##,##0.00;[$₹]##,##0.00;`

[image]
[image]

Not sure about `>999...` conditions, you do not mention those.

Comment: I'd forgotten about that - nice!

Comment: i want those conditions as well

Comment: @Code Guy, update your question with more details then.

Comment: Done please check